# Creating a Column for Bins in DF based on numerical column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, data-science, bins

I have a df that looks like,

```
ID | Time_A | Time_B
B     5.0      3.5
C     3.0      4.0
A     2.5      1.0
```

I want to create a new column that classifies Time_B column into Bins of 0-5, 5-10, 10-15, 15-20, and 20 - anything larger. Where none of the bins have overlapping values, ( where 5 does not exist in 5-10 if it exists in 0-5.

Thanks!

Comment: you are looking at `pd.cut(df.Time_B, bins=[0,5,10,15,20,np.inf], include_lowest=True)`.

Comment: thanks!, what does the include lowest do? does it mean each bin will include the lowest? but I did not want overlap in any value for the bins @QuangHoang

Comment: `include_lowest` will include the `0` value to your lowest bin. Otherwise, a `0` value would give a `NaN` cut. If you don't mind this or don't have `0` in the data, then you can ignore this option.

Comment: Thanks, so for each Bin the highest value for that bin which is the lowest value in next bin will only appear in the bin where it is the highest correct? @QuangHoang

Comment: Yes, there a `closed` option for `qcut` which defaults to `'right'`.

Comment: what is the difference between qcut just cut as you showed above? sorry  @QuangHoang

Comment: Thanks @QuangHoang so if I wanted to do that, just replace the pd.cut with pd.qcut and add that closed parameter?

Comment: Oh, I missed that. `qcut` divides your columns into (almost) equal size, while `cut` divides your column by values. So you definitely want `cut` here.

Comment: ahh, got it so use that closed parameter with cut not qcut? @QuangHoang

Comment: Yes, I wasn't thinking properly. `qcut` has nothing to do with your question.

Comment: @QuangHoang Thanks, so you mentioned just use the closed option under the same cut method ? thanks!

Comment: Yes, but you want the default behavior, so you don't need to do anything.

Comment: Thanks @QuangHoang